# How to set memento in memento pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, memento

I need to write a Graph class which performs some sort of operations and gives possibility to save it using memento pattern. I am trying to implement that functionality, but I want to have `IGraph` interface which cannot return explicit type of `ConcreteMemento` so it returns `Memento` interface, but because of that I need to downcast it inside `Graph` class.

So my question is, is it a good practise or am I missing something in memento pattern?
Also is it possible to implement `ConcreteMemento` in the way that only `Graph` can access some of its methods?

`Grahp`

```
class ConcreteMemento : Memento
{

}
internal class Graph : IGraph
{
    public Memento GetMemento()
    {
        return new ConcreteMemento();
    }

    public void SetMemento(Memento m)
    {
        var concreteMemento = m as ConcreteMemento;
    }
}
```

`IGraph`

```
public interface Memento
{

}
interface IGraph
{
    Memento GetMemento();
}
```

Comment: [Refactoring Guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/memento) has an excellent article explaining this. Specifically see the section under _Structure_ where three alternative implementations are shown.

Comment: Thanks, but it's actually not what I am asking about. He has two possible implementations of this pattern but first is the case above, second does not allow me to for example save state to file (because I assume that app can be restarted), but thank you for responding @jaco0646

Comment: Why do you say, "two possible implementations" when the article clearly shows three?